# What does it mean for "if COMMAND" to pass through the exit status of COMMAND?

Tags: bash

Referring to the guide at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html, there is a line saying: The "if COMMAND" construct returns the exit status of COMMAND.

I understand how the if construct works, but somehow do not understand what this sentence mean. I think the guide at http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html explains it much more clearly. Is there something I'm missing in the ABS guide?

Comment: FYI, the ABS is a very very poor reference. It's advisable not to use it. The bash-hackers wiki or the wooledge wiki are both much better.

Comment: ...the corresponding page on the Wooledge wiki is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29; the corresponding page on the bash-hackers wiki is http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/if_clause

Comment: I see. Thanks for the recommendations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What that means is this:

```
if false; then
  :
else
  echo "Exit status is $?"
fi
```

The exit status of `false` is passed through, so the `$?` showing that exit status is still available in the `echo` invoked as the subsequent line.

---

A case where whether a construct passes through exit status is more directly important is variable assignments.

Compare the following two:

```
# passes through exit status
var=$(echo "hello"; false) # var=hello; $?=1

# masks exit status
declare var=$(echo "hello"; false) # var=hello; $?=0
```

`declare` (like `local`) does not pass through the exit status of any command substitutions performed during the assignment; thus, it masks any failures which might occur, by returning its own exit status (of 0, unless it was passed an invalid variable name or otherwise had an error in its own operation).

Thus, if you want to declare a variable local and assign a value from command substitution without throwing away exit status, the best practice is to use two separate lines:

```
somefunc() {                  # local only makes sense inside a function
  local var                   # declare your local variables first...
  var=$(echo "hello"; false)  # ...then use them separately.
}
```